# Why aren't my breakpoints working correctly in FDT's debugger?

Tags: actionscript-3, fdt

I'm having a frustrating problem using FDT's debugger (I'm using FDT 4 on OSX) when I set breakpoints in my code. Basically, when I set a breakpoint the debugger should show the value of variables in the function where the breakpoint is set. This works correctly with one application that I'm working on:

[image: debugger working]

However with another application I'm developing it terminates the process and I can't see any variables:

[image: debugger not working]

I would really like to be able to inspect the value of variables when I set a breakpoint, but whenever it hits a breakpoint the debugger keeps doing that.

Because it works correctly on another application I'm assuming there is something I need to do in my build configuration, but I have no idea what. Hopefully someone can give me some pointers on what to look for.

Comment: To clarify, the debugger terminates when it hits a break point - correct? What is the SDK you're using? Is the SDK the same for the working project and for the 'broken' one. There are issues with the 4.6 SDK that we are aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debugger that ships with the Flex 4.6 SDK breaks FDT's debugger. The FDT team is aware of it and has already fixed it. The fix has not been released yet; however, it is part of the 5.1 release that is scheduled for January.

You can follow more here:
http://bugs.powerflasher.com/jira/browse/FDT-2423

Try using a different Flex SDK for your project & debugging.

Comment: aha, switching the SDK fixed it. I was using 4.5.1 on the working project and 3.5 on the other. After I switched it to 4.5.1 the debugger works fine.